# Bash script to loop through file name to delete at specific index

Tags: file, bash, rename

I have a ton of files that are named like this:

```
nn - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-OOO.ext
```

Where `nn` is always a two digit number and `xxxxx` is a variable length of text. (The suffix of -OOO is static throughout all of the files). What should be in the loop to rename the files to:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ext
```

Thus removing the `nn -`(always the first 5 characters) and the `-OOO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with two substring operations:

```
$ name="nn - xxxx x xx xx xxxxx-OOO.ext"
$ part1=${name:5}                   # substring starting at position 5
$ part2=${part1%-OOO.ext}           # remove `-OOO.ext` at the end of $part1
$ final="$part2".ext
$ echo $final
xxxx x xx xx xxxxx.ext
$ mv "$name" "$final"
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the loop construct. Could you please display that as well?

Comment: What do you have so far for that, and why did you ask for what should go in the loop then?

Comment: I currently have "for f in *.ext;", but I don't know how to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $file_name | sed "s/.*-\s*\(.*\)-.*/\1.ext/"` will give you the "xxxxxxx.ext" as you asked for in the OP.